# Streaming dynamic playlist with GPAC

Tags: video-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box

After dozens of hours of googling and thoroughly reading every piece of info, I'm still unable to start dynamic MPD broadcasting.

I've installed GPAC version 2.3-DEV-rev832-g799d9e547-master.
My OS Ubuntu 22

My goal is simple:
I getting short videofiles from time to time, and I want to combine them to "pseudo-stream".
My files have length exactly 30s, and I want to append them dynamically

`gpac -i pl.m3u:ka=2000 -o live.mpd:dmode=dynamic`

The playlist is very simple

```
##begin pl,m3u
../segment_0000.mp4
../segment_0001.mp4
##end playlist
```

What I get -- is a bunch of m4s files and few mp4 files, along with live.mpd file.

When i'm trying to play it, i have errors.

FFplay:
hundreds of such:

```
[dash @ 0x7f2228000cc0] Failed to open fragment of playlist f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 2188 times
[dash @ 0x7f2228000cc0] Failed to open fragment of playlist f=0/0
```

mpv:
hundreds of such

```
[ffmpeg/demuxer] dash: Failed to open fragment of playlist
[ffmpeg/demuxer] dash: Failed to open fragment of playlist
```

And in the browser dash.js is just not playing.

MPD file does not containing any relative paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 2.3-DEV-rev832-g799d9e547-master at 2024-01-29T19:47:00.512Z -->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.000S" type="dynamic" availabilityStartTime="2024-01-29T19:47:00.510Z" publishTime="2024-01-29T19:47:00.512Z" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT0H0M1.000S" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H0M30.000S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="https://gpac.io">
  <Title>live.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period id="DID1" start="PT0H0M0.000S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" startWithSAP="1">
   <SegmentTemplate media="segment_0000_dash_track1_$Number$.m4s" initialization="segment_0000_dash_track1_init.mp4" timescale="12800" startNumber="1" duration="12800"/>
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001F" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1812813">
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
   <SegmentTemplate media="segment_0000_dash_track2_$Number$.m4s" initialization="segment_0000_dash_track2_init.mp4" timescale="44100" startNumber="1" duration="44100"/>
   <Representation id="2" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100" bandwidth="1407">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

I'm frustrated, it's critical thing in all my project, but i was unable to create the very basic playlist.
Any help is really appreciated...